# How to get data from the last http request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a problem that the http request takes the data from the last petition loaded. And not from the last http request.

[image: waterfall network]

Is there someway to stop the last call and get the new one?

**Component**

```
this.searchForm$.valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe((selectedValue) => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.sExperienceSearch = {...selectedValue.sExperience,...selectedValue.sExperience2,...selectedValue.sExperience3,...selectedValue.sExperience4}
        this.sExperienceSearch.importanceMap = {...selectedValue.sExperience.importanceMap,...selectedValue.sExperience2.importanceMap}
        this.apiService
            .getSearch(this.sExperienceSearch)
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.firstCall = false;
                this.loading = false;
                this.selectedValue = this.sExperienceSearch;
                this.searchData = data;
                this.numVendors = this.searchData.numVendors
                    ? this.searchData.numVendors
                    : 0;
            });
    });
}
```

**Service**

```
 return this.httpClient
        .post<any[]>('/api/advanced-search', body, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map((data) => {
                return data;
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
                return throwError('Something went wrong!');
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component you use multiple subscribes (after each search event) and this causes the longes lasting http call to provide the answer.

What you want is to cancel the subscription to a http-call as soon as a new search request comes in. This ensures that you only get the result for the search that started last and not the result that finishes last.

You're already using RxJS pipe operators; you have to take a look at the switchMap operator to achieve what you want. Below a hint for the direction.

component-logic:

```
this.searchForm$.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((selectedValue) => {
        this.sExperienceSearch = {...selectedValue.sExperience,...selectedValue.sExperience2,...selectedValue.sExperience3,...selectedValue.sExperience4}
        this.sExperienceSearch.importanceMap = {...selectedValue.sExperience.importanceMap,...selectedValue.sExperience2.importanceMap}
        return this.apiService.getSearch(this.sExperienceSearch)
      })
    ).subscribe(...subscribelogic...)
```